# How to make an array dynamic in component class of Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I want to make fieldValues arrar dynamic in component class of Angular 6.

```
*ngFor="let fieldValue of fieldValues" [value]="fieldValue.name"
```

I make array like this

```
fieldValues: Array<any>;
```

how can i make this array 'fieldValues' dynamic in component class of Angular 6.

export class UserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{

```
valueMap=new Map();
fieldValuesActSegent: Array<any>;
fieldValuesAccountType: Array<any>;


constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,

}

getValues(fieldName) {

    console.log("Value of map"+this.valueMap);
    var obj = this.valueMap.get(fieldName);
    console.log(this.valueMap.get(fieldName));
    switch (fieldName) {
        case 'A' : {
            this.fieldValues = this.valueMap.get(fieldName)
            break;
        }
        case 'B' : {
            this.fieldValues = this.valueMap.get(fieldName)
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you describe more or more code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you expecting example like this.

```js
<div *ngFor="let fieldValue of fieldValues" >
  <input id="{{fieldValue.Id}}" [value]="{{fieldValue.name}}">
</div>
```

If this is not what you are expecting.Please provide more details..

Comment: i want to make fieldValues array dynamic in component class because i have to use it in many different input fields.